# How to open .chm help file in c#

Tags: c#, chm

I have opened .chm file in c# but it is showing This program cannot display webpage error .

I have edited register and my path does not contain any special character , can any one help me out of this .

---

### Error Details :

> This program cannot display the webpage 
>          Most likely causes: You are not connected to the Internet.  The website is encountering problems.  There might be a typing error in
>   the address. 
>        What you can try: 
>        Check your Internet connection. Try visiting another website to make sure you are connected.
>
> ```
>  Retype the address.  
>
>  Go back to the previous page. 
>  More information  More information**
> ```

Comment: Showing your code would really help.  Additionally, you may need to right-click on the .chm file in Windows Explorer and unblock it, especially if it was downloaded from a different location.

Comment: This problem repeatedly occurs with me, even when opening the file with Internet Explorer. There are some tools that decompile and decompress the *.chm files to *.html files availabile in the web

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094053/open-chm-help-file-in-c-sharp help?

Comment: @Tim : How to unblock ? Can you please elaborate .

Answer (score 1):

The issue may be because the .chm is on a network share and not local, as Windows can only open them if they're local files. It was [patched as a security issue apparently](http://www.helpscribble.com/chmnetwork.html).

The usual way around this is to install a copy of the .chm with your app.

Comment: As I noted in my comment above, he may also need to unblock the file if it's downloaded from another location.  Using a local copy in any case would be better - especially if it's a large .chm file.