# C#- i want to add a help file in my wpf application?

Tags: c#, wpf, chm

I want to add help.chm or help.pdf in application.

Where to add these files and how to call them during button click or on F1 key pressed?

i have also used following code for F1 key press but i am not able to call the help file any how

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command='ApplicationCommands.Help' Executed='Window_Help_Executed'></CommandBinding>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Please Provide me any Solution.

Thanks

Comment: And what is inside `void Window_Help_Executed()` ?  Have you tried a breakpoint?

Comment: This Stackoverflow question may help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094053/open-chm-help-file-in-c-sharp

Comment: i put a messagebox here it is working fine but when i am trying to access my help.chm and help.pdf through `Help.ShowHelp` and `Process.Start` i am not able to view any of the file. files are there in my application directory where all the class files and windows are lying.

Comment: @mircea i already tried that way.....

Comment: Try with a very simple app. Check the path to the file to be correct. Check also the .chm file integrity. Use a full path to specify the file.

Comment: So, the XAML code is working and the C# code is not. Then please post the code behind.

Comment: @mircea actually i am not able to get the file path and not able to integrate the .chm file.

Comment: @HenkHolterman i am trying to access it through `Process.Start(@"help.chm")` and also by `Help.ShowHelp(null,@"help.chm")` both are not working.

Comment: Use a hard coded full path like c:\file.chm in order to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open your help file with the `Process` class... view the [Process Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) page at MSDN for more information:

```
Process.Start("help.chm");
```

For this to work, you will need to place the 'help.chm' file in the 'bin' folder where your executable is. You *could* put this file elsewhere as long as you use the correct relative path from your application executable file to it. You will also need to add the following:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
```

Comment: thanks.... is there any other way?

Comment: This *is* the way... your problem is probably that your help file is not in the correct folder. Move it to the exact `bin` folder that you are currently building into, eg. if you are running in the `x86` platform and `Debug` configuration, then you should move the help file to the YourAppName > bin > Debug folder. If you still have problems, for testing, move it to the root of the C drive and call this code: `Process.Start("C:\\help.chm");`