# Access violation when closing help file (.chm) C#

Tags: c#, .net, access-violation, chm

I'm developing a C# application and made a (.chm) help file to link it with, and I use the following statement to open help file:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this,HelpFileLocation);
```

And the help file opens correctly, but when I close the help file window, the application terminates and the debugging stops, and when looking at the output window I see this:

> app.exe has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'

I tried to call the method from more than one form and I'm getting the same problem.

EDIT: this is a GIF describes the problem: https://archive.org/download/chm_20200125/chm.gif

Comment: try running app has an admin and see

Comment: you can also try this for further debugging , `Debug -> Options and Settings -> Debugging -> General -> Enable Just My Code"`

Comment: @Clint
The problem isn't in the debug only, but also when run without debugging

Comment: yes but by enabling the above setting, you might be able to narrow down your issue

Comment: @Clint
I'll give it a try

Comment: @Clint
`Just My Code` is already enabled and no further debug info :(

Comment: Did you try running your exe as admin and could you pls update your question with some code as to how you're invoking your chm file

Comment: How do you close the help file window? Where resides your CHM file in a subfolder of your app? Can you open by double click and close the CHM without problems?

Comment: @Clint
- Run as admin didn't help.
- Closing the help file the simple way of "X" button.
- CHM location doesn't matter.
-  I can open by double click and close the CHM without problems.

Comment: Sounds a Registry issue. Try your application in another machine. And check [this](https://wikifixes.com/en/errors/0x/0xC0000005/?gclid=CjwKCAiA66_xBRBhEiwAhrMuLaarVK0Ix7gVzLk0mfVg0sti9l7vnI1REMJ6QMHr-iqKKMElFKoAwBoCxNkQAvD_BwE).

Comment: @Clint
this is a gif of the problem
https://archive.org/download/chm_20200125/chm.gif

Comment: is it necessary to use Help.Show, why not try process.start ?

Comment: I tried this in WPF and it worked without error `Help.ShowHelp(null,HelpFileLocation);`

Comment: already used `null`, anyway I made a webhelp instead of html, thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this thread can help you.
[Open CHM (help file) in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094053/open-chm-help-file-in-c-sharp)

Access violation.. Maybe the app is not executed with the rights to open the file? Maybe it has to be executed with admin privileges? Or the file is opened in another application already?

Comment: This is the problem
https://archive.org/download/chm_20200125/chm.gif

Comment: Google says that (0xc0000005) 'Access violation' is a memory access violation. Maybe after closing the help window your program is using a pointer or something to some point in memory, where you shouldn't go?

Comment: This is exactly what I am thinking, but how to figure it out !!??

Comment: I am afraid this is a problem that I can no longer help with. Maybe this Site helps you. [link](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/how-to-fix-error-code-0xc0000005-in-windows/)